# Initiating new orders with active "order-session" only?

Tags: fx, algorithmic-trading, liquidity, fix, quickfix

Is it a must to establish "quote-session" & subscribing to quotes/market data before initiating a "New Order-single(Market-GTC)"?
I actually can't see any use of quote-session for trading activities & my FIX-bridge is opening "single-new orders" using "order-session" only.

The reason i want to avoid  quote-session:
1.It can add up to over-all processing time/latency
2.I can logon to quote-session & use the quote-flow from a different application.
Any thoughts on these?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is depends where you want to trade and it is part of trading workflow of concrete counterparty. FIX protocol definition itself does not  force you to subscribe on anything.

Some brokerages forced you to subscribe on market data streams prior placing any trades. Last one we discovered - FXDD.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not a requirement to initiate new orders with active "order-session" only. When trading FX you want to try and minimize over-all processing time/latency whenever possible. This will increase your profits and consistency.

Yes. It is always possible to log in to the quote-session and use the quote-flow from another application to maintain flexibility.